# Android-image upload issue to a REST server: Image format not supported

Tags: android, image, rest, netbeans, multipart

I'm trying to upload an image from my Android app to a rest server. The images does get uploaded but ,on the server machine, the photo viewer or another image app can't open the uploaded images.
I'm using glassfish 3 in netbeans 7 on the server machine. I'm not using maven and i'd prefer a non-moven solution.

Here's the code i use for uploading the images from android in a Runnable

```
@Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
try{

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 77, out);
                byte[] data = out.toByteArray();

                ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data,"image.JPG");

                MultipartEntityBuilder mpeb = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                mpeb.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                mpeb.addBinaryBody("file", data, ContentType.create("image/jpg"), "image.jpeg");
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
                request.setEntity(mpeb.build());
                request.addHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request,httpContext);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 201){
                    Log.w("ced", "pic success");
                }else{
                    Log.w("ced", "pic failed ,code "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("error",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

And the code to receive the images on the server machine.

```
@POST
@Path("/imgs/")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response saveImage(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream is
                          ){
    try {

        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new     File("C:/Users/files/Downloads/"+"img.jpg"));

        Utils.copyFileStream(is, os);

        os.flush();
        os.close();
        return Response.status(201).entity("reached").build();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RestW.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,     null, ex);
    }catch(IOException e){
         Logger.getLogger(RestW.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
 return Response.status(500).entity("error").build();

}
```

I've included the following jars (not all at once)in the server web but still nothing's changed:
httpmime-4.4.1.jar
httpcore-4.4.1.jar
jersey-server-1.18.jar
jersey-servlet-1.18.jar
mimepull-1.9.3.jar
jersey-media-multipart-2.0.jar
jersey-core-1.18.jar

I've tried changing the mime type to multipart/form-data and multipart/* in addBinaryBody. Still, the images can't be opened.

When i add another @FormDataParam() ( for content disposition ) it displays the following error:

SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
 SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.proj.test.RestW.saveImage(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition), annotated with POST of resource, class com.proj.test.RestW, is not recognized as valid resource method.

When i remove the content disposition parameter, it works fine but the image can't be opened.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code that worked for me

```
private void sendPics(ArrayList<String> paths){

        for(int i = 0;i<paths.size();i++){
            String p = paths.get(i);

            try{
            Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(p);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            byte[] data = out.toByteArray();

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.write(data);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
            int c = connection.getResponseCode();

            connection.disconnect();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("cedError",e.getMessage());
        }
        }   

    }
}
```